# Ajax based personal messaging system in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, messaging

I am trying to build a MySQL, PHP, Ajax based personal messaging system.

There is one table for all messages - `msghistory`, which looks like that

[image]

And another one for users' last message check date records - `chkdate`.

The system works like this:

When user signs into page, page fires Ajax autocheck. Ajax calls php in every 10 sec. PHP side checks for new messages by user id. At first checks `chkdate`, then checks `msghistory`: If there are no message after last check date then system will not notify user, else will notify about this

I think this way will load server heavily, if there are 1000s of users. I wonder if explained above way is optimal? if not, what do you think about this, which way is better?

Comment: No, it is definitly not.

Comment: On a more serious note: You should look at long polling - a short poll every 10 seconds is quite exhausting when user counts climb

Comment: As I said: long polling. This means, that your client starts a poll, the server does NOT immediately return from the poll, but keeps it waiting for either an event (message) or a timeout (maybe minutes) this way the huge overhead of the HTTP transaction, PHP startup, etc. is incurred only much fewer times.

Comment: @EugenRieck so I think increasing ajax interval up to 2 min will solve everything, right?

Comment: It sure won't solve everything (most definitly not the Euro dept crisis), but it will help: 1000 users, 10 seconds poll = 100 requests/second just for the poll, might be 200 or 300 queries/second to the database. Same thing with 2 minutes=120 seconds makes 17 or 25 queries/second

Comment: As I said: Long polling - this gives you **immediate** notification on a new message, but without the horrific overhead of a 10s poll.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7445/discussion-between-trl13-and-eugen-rieck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long polling is a good idea. Here's approximately how it works (though you can vary the lengths of time used). Have your PHP script (the one the client requests) run a (semi-)infinite loop that checks for a new message in the database. If no message is found, use the sleep() function to wait for ten seconds or so before the loop goes through again. Once a message is found, send it out to the client and break out of the loop. The client can then display the message, then start a new request to the "long polling" PHP script, another ten seconds later.

Here is a demo PHP script:
$username=$_GET["username"];

```
<?php
while(1) {
    $messages=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `msghistory` WHERE `to_id`='$username'");
    if (!mysql_num_rows($messages) === 0) {
        //do whatever message processing and printout you need to do here
        break;//break out of the loop. the script terminates and returns its messages to the client
    }
}
?>
```

In the near future, we are going to see the implementation of WebSockets, which allow for real-time, push-pull communication between client and server. In many cases, though, this technology is not yet ready for use. Until then, long polling is the way to go.

Comment: Don't do this unless your http server is designed to handle lots of simultaneous connections. Apache, for example, is configured by default to only spawn a handful of threads. Meaning after the first few users connect your website will be unreachable.

Comment: I second Kane's note. Apache will be better able to handle tens of thousands of short finite connections better than a few hundred persistent connections. Regardless of which direction you go (long-polling vs ajax) You might want to think about setting up a lighter webserver dedicated to the chat... something like Lighttpd or Nginx which can have larger numbers of max_clients or a larger number of simultaneous requests given the same memory/CPU conditions.